# Pass parameters from C# .cs to .xslt

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, parameters

I'm trying to find an easy way to pass parameters from my C# class file (.cs) to my .xslt file. I'm not really working with a .xml file, so I don't know if something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx    will work for me. Also, I don't have a main method since it is just a class (this is all being done in .net). Does anybody know of a possible way to do this?

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
        settings.EnableScript = true;
        FetchQuote();

        // Create the XslCompiledTransform and load the stylesheet
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load("Home.xslt");

        // Create the XsltArgumentList
        XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();

        // Add parameters
        xslArg.AddParam("chart_url", "","Chart_Url");
        xslArg.AddParam("last", "", "Last");
        xslArg.AddParam("change", "", "Change");
        xslArg.AddParam("perc_change", "", "Perc_Change");

        // Transform the File
        using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"))
        {
            xslt.Transform("", xslArg, w);
        }



    }
```

Comment: You're going to need to give us a better example. Right now, it's impossible for us to tell what you're actually asking for.

Comment: @Justin Niessner is right, it's difficult to understand what you need.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how to explain this. I want to pass over some string values from a .cs file. All of these files are part of a big website. We are retrieving some information from the web in this .cs file (from the google finance api). I need to get that information into my .xslt file (which defines the home page of this website) I do'nt know that I can post any code yet. Does that work, or do you still need more specifications? (I want to be able to use these string values that I retrieve in my .cs file in my .xslt file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:kso="nothin">

<xsl:param name="yourParam" />


   public static string Transform(string xml, string xsl, XsltArgumentList argsList)
        {
            XDocument selectedXml = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XslCompiledTransform xmlTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

            StringBuilder htmlOutput = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(htmlOutput);

            xmlTransform.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xsl)));
            xmlTransform.Transform(selectedXml.CreateReader(), argsList, writer);

            return htmlOutput.ToString();
        }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();

    // Add parameters
    xslArg.AddParam("chart_url", "","Chart_Url");
    xslArg.AddParam("last", "", "Last");
    xslArg.AddParam("change", "", "Change");
    xslArg.AddParam("perc_change", "", "Perc_Change");



  string output=Transform(string.empty,"Home.xslt",xslArg );

  Response.Clear();
  Response.Write(output);

  //or:
  //string output=Transform("<xmlroot/>","Home.xslt",xslArg );
 }
```

Comment: How am I supposed to utilize this? You do realize I only have a .xslt file to work with, I don't have a separate ".xml" and ".xsl" file right?

Comment: Actually, I have a method where I am retrieving the info from a url like so:  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);    (the url is the url for the google api where I am retreiving information from)

Comment: You can pass an empty xml string or an empty xml root node. If you don't need that!

Comment: also, will it affect me at all that I'm retrieving all the data in a .cs file (one that doesn't have a main method). All the examples i've seen use a main method.

Comment: This Transform method take parameters and return a string, It is not important where data comes from.

Comment: Okay - I posted my current method up above - should I change things?

Comment: I don't understand why I need a "string" method? What is "Transform" doing? and when does it ever get used/called?

Comment: Okay, I see that, but there is still a string method.

Comment: I suggest to try this code, debug it! There's no "string method" string is the type of the variable returning from the transformation.

Comment: I understand that, I was just trying to refer to that method that returns a string. Where does that string called "output" ever get used? In the Response.Write?

Comment: Yes! It's used there! I put it in a variable so you can easly debug it!

Comment: Oh okay, I'm having a problem. There isn't something just called "Response". We have HttpResponse, WebResponse, etc. Which should I choose?

Comment: Try "Page.Response.Write(...);"

Comment: The other problem I'm having is that I don't think my C# code ever gets run. An object of that class is never instantiated, so I don't know how to work around that.

Comment: I'm still getting an error saying that an object reference is required for the non-static method, field, or property.